# Slow transition animation on Android using React Stack Navigation v4

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Our app had the feature of showing the bottom tabBar in the main screens and hiding it when the user navigates to another one (changing the stack), but after migration from v3 to the v4, the Android app is slower when opening a screen and the transition of closing the screen is also slower, and apparently every time I navigate to a stack it renders all stack navigation that exists inside the bottom tab navigation, even when not navigating to it.
It gets worse on the production app that have 5 tabs and have some animation during the opening.

How can I solve this problem of jumpty animation?

Tested on Galaxy Nexus API 29 - Android 10.
The same problems happens on a Moto G7 Play, Android 10

[image: jumpy animation]

Here is the navigations code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-tabs';
import {
  createAppContainer,
  createSwitchNavigator
} from "react-navigation";
import { SafeAreaProvider } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import Example, { EmptyScreen } from "./screens/Example";
import { StatusBar } from 'react-native';

const SlowStack = createStackNavigator({
  SlowExample: { screen: Example, params: { tabBarVisible: true } },
  Details: {
    screen: EmptyScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      headerTitle: "Slow on Close"
    },
    params: { tabBarVisible: false }
  }
});

SlowStack.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }: any) => {
  // console.warn('SlowStack')
  const { params = { tabBarVisible: true } } = navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index];
  return {
    tabBarLabel: 'SlowStack',
    tabBarVisible: params.tabBarVisible // The change on the visibility of tabBar generates the laggy transition
  };
};

const MainTabs = createBottomTabNavigator({
  SlowStack: {
    screen: SlowStack,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: "SlowStack"
    }
  },
});

const AppSwitchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  Auth: {
    screen: MainTabs
  },
});

const AppNavigator = createAppContainer(AppSwitchNavigator);

export const App = () => (
  <SafeAreaProvider>
    <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
    <AppNavigator />
  </SafeAreaProvider>
)

export default App;
```

Here is the full code:
https://snack.expo.io/@ronicesarrc/slow-react-navigation-example

PS: This problem does not happen if I do not hide/show the bottom tab bar dynamically or use Android 5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamically changing the `tabBarVisible` is not recommended for the reasons you're experiencing right now:

The documentation says:

> Some tab navigators such as bottom tab navigator also have a tabBarVisible option which can be used to hide the tab bar based on instructions in the Screen options resolution guide. However, we don't recommend using it since showing/hiding the tab bar mid-navigation can affect the animation of the stack navigator causing glitchy behaviour.

Source: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hiding-tabbar-in-screens/

---

Instead of hiding the tab bar dynamically I would change the structure of your navigators instead where your main navigator is your stack navigator and where your tab navigator is a screen of your stack navigator. So you can do something like this:

```
const MainTabs = createBottomTabNavigator({
  SlowExample: {
    screen: Example,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: "Example"
    }
  },
});

const SlowStack = createStackNavigator({
  SlowExample: { screen: MainTabs },
  Details: {
    screen: EmptyScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      headerTitle: "Slow on Close"
    },
  }
});

SlowStack.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }: any) => {
  return {
    tabBarLabel: 'SlowStack',
  };
};

const AppSwitchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  Auth: {
    screen: SlowStack
  },
});

const AppNavigator = createAppContainer(AppSwitchNavigator);

export const App = () => (
  <SafeAreaProvider>
    <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
    <AppNavigator />
  </SafeAreaProvider>
)
```

Since `EmptyScreen` is only contained inside the stack navigator it won't show the tabs when you're on this screen, only the header.

Added benefit to this approach is that you also don't have to pass parameters to get it to work.

Comment: You are right, changing the order of the navigator it worked and hide the bottom bar without the `tabBarVisible` https://snack.expo.io/@ronicesarrc/react-navigation-with-bottom-tabs-stack-navigator-switch-navigator. Now I will try doing the same on the production app. Thanks